# Cleaning out a field of Phone numbers in mySql

Tags: mysql

In not a database guy but:  I have mixed up data in a mySql database that I inherited.

Some Phone numbers are formatted  `(512) 555-1212`  (call it dirty)
Others  `5125551212`  (Call it clean)

I need a sqlstamet that says

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Phone="clean'(Some sort of cleaning code  -  regex?)
WHERE Phone='Dirty'
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no regex replace/update in MySQL. If it's just parentheses and dashes and spaces then some nested `REPLACE` calls will do the trick:

```
UPDATE table_name
SET Phone = REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(Phone, '-', ''), ')', ''), '(', ''), ' ', '')
```

Answer (score 0):

To my knowledge you can't run a regexp to replace data during the update process. Only during the SELECT statement.

Your best bet is to use a scripting language that you're familiar with and read the table and change it that way. Basically by retrieving all the entries. Then using a string replace to match a simple regexp such as `[^\d]*` and remove those characters. Then update the table with the new value.

Also, see this answer:
[How to do a regular expression replace in MySQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986826/how-to-do-a-regular-expression-replace-in-mysql)